# Is Drools 'and' keyword act as bitwise &?

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I am trying to write a sliding window rule where I have multiple conditions. The rule I am trying to write is :

```
rule "1"
when
$test : Test (num1 > 100 && num2 > 101) && $number:Number() from accumulate(Test($t : num1) over window:time(20s), sum($t))
then
    System.out.println("Output is "+$test.getNum1()+" and sum is "+$number+"");
end
```

In the above rule, the engine is accumulating the values of num1 and num2 even if they are not satisfying the condition. The `&&` keyword is working as bitwise AND i.e it is evaluating both LHS and RHS. 
Can anyone explain to me about this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you have 2 completely independent patterns: there are no reference to on pattern from the other. Drools will then evaluate these patterns independently.

What you could do is either write everything in a single pattern:

`$number:Number() from accumulate(Test($t : num1 > 100, num2 > 101) over window:time(20s), sum($t))`

Or to make a "join" between the patterns:

```
$test : Test (num1 > 100 && num2 > 101) && $number:Number() from accumulate(Test(this == $test, $t : num1) over window:time(20s), sum($t))
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: how can I get the test object in my then part if I am following your first method of writing this rule?

Comment: It all depends on what you want in your RHS. if you have 300 `Test` objects and let's say that 50 of them match the range constraint, how many times would you like the RHS to be executed and what do you expect the value of `$number` to be in each of them?

Comment: I want to get al the occurrence of that event i.e 50 times as per your question. I also want some parameters from the current Test object to be used in my RHS part of the rule. Let's say I want the value of num3 variable whenever the condition is satified.

Comment: You could then use a `collectList` accumulate function instead of a `sum`.

Comment: ok, Thank you. One last Question. Is there any way to get the latest event from the working memory in drools?

Comment: if your events have a timestamp (or an incremental id), you could do something like: `$last: Test() not Test(timestamp < $last.timestamp)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196508/discussion-between-prog-g-and-esteban-aliverti).